# Applescript: Emailing a http link

Tags: http, email, hyperlink, applescript

I've created an applescript program that ends with emailing some predefined text including a link, but I've no idea how to make it so the web address is actually a link instead of just text.
Does anyone know how I'd go about doing that?

Here's my code so far: (not that it's really needed for this problem)

```
set theFile to choose file    tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
set fileName to (text 1 thru ((length of fileName) - 3) of fileName)
set presetText to "Hello,
Files Uploaded:

" & fileName & "

To access our FTP Server: 
http://217.207.130.162:8080/WebInterface/login.html   

To access our FTP server, log onto our website below: 

Username: 
Password: 


Thanks, 
Joe"

tell application "Mail"
activate
set theMEssage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:fileName, content:presetText}
end tell
```

Comment: There's nothing to do. When the email is sent the link will be clickable for the recipient. It happens automatically. Test it yourself by sending the email to yourself.

Comment: Thanks regulus, if you put this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to your post, there's nothing to do. When the email is sent the link will be clickable for the recipient. It happens automatically. Test it yourself by sending the email to yourself.